# Fill up DataSet will CultureInfo

Tags: c#, .net

I'm Trying to:

1. Take all CultureInfo and put it into array
2. Put it to DataSet
3. And finnaly fill up DataGridView

This is part of code that i wrote, but it only put information to DataGridView without DataSet. How to connect CultureInfo -> DataSet -> DataGridView?

```
 CultureInfo[] culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
        dgv.DataSource = culture;
        dgv.Refresh();
```

Comment: Why do you need a DataSet of it?

Comment: what is the problem and why are trying to do this?

Comment: I mean if you want a dataset, just create one, add columns, then add the rows... but I agree with the above comments... maybe do you mean not a LITERAL dataset?  What's happening, and how do we help?

Comment: I would like to add dataset for it but i don't know how add columns/rows.

The reason is learning

Comment: It sounds to me like what you really want is to display the CultureInfo. If so you don't need a dataset you can just convert to a list. Unless this a specific homework assignment, having to utilize a DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You will have to add the System.Collections.Generic library, to use the ToList() method. A GridView can consume a list<>

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Use it in your page load (something like this:)

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    CultureInfo[] culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
        dgv.DataSource = culture.ToList();
        dgv.DataBind();
 }
```